# Is it possible to marshal a Go struct while including a map name?

Tags: dictionary, go, yaml, marshalling

Say that I have a go struct that is set up like this:

```
type TestStruct struct {
    ID string
    ConfigTest         map[string]Object
    
}
```

With the object inside having yaml and/or json tags, for marshalling and later saving into a file, like this:

```
type Object struct {
    ID          string  `yaml:"ID"`
    Value       float64 `yaml:"Value"`
}
```

So, when I marshal the `TestStruct.ConfigTest`, and save it to a file using `ioutil.WriteFile()` I get something like this as the output:

```
obj1:
    ID: "Hello"
    Value: 1.2
obj2:
    ID: "World"
    Value: 3.4
...(etc)
```

But what I actually want is to marshal, and save the file like this:

```
Objects:  
    obj1:
        ID: "Hello"
        Value: 1.2
    obj2:
        ID: "World"
        Value: 3.4
    ...(etc)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two basic choices:

**Reuse `TestStruct`:**

Change `TestStruct` to have the appropriate labels on the fields: one to skip marshaling ID, the other to give the desired name to `ConfigTest`.

```
type TestStruct struct {
  ID string                             `yaml:"-"`
  ConfigTest         map[string]Object  `yaml:"Objects"`
}
```

**Use a wrapper struct:**

If you can't, or don't want to, modify `TestStruct` (ie: because it's already marshaled somewhere else), you can use a wrapper struct:

```
type WrapperStruct struct {
  ConfigTest         map[string]Object  `yaml:"Objects"`
}
```

And marshal your new wrapper struct instead of `MyStruct`.

Comment: Can the labels on the fields be edited on demand? That is, would it be possible to choose what can/cannot be marshalled given a specific function call or if/else statement?

Comment: I am asking that as the TestStruct struct will probably be filled with more entities like ConfigTest, so I'd like to only marshal out specific ones when I like.

Comment: I don't think struct tags can be manipulated with reflection. If you need that, you may want to do some partially custom marshaling (eg: marshal TestStruct.ConfigTest and modify the output the way you need it).